# Trying to fix visual studio code settings

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've already tried removing files, and uninstalling and reinstalling, but there is just something wrong with my terminal in vs code, I'm about to go insane. I want the terminal, so it shows the file at the top and I can execute functions from the file without each line showing the folder information, If it doesn't make sense I'll show two photos.[vscode terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gdks.png)[IDLE Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnmbM.png). Essentially I want the vscode terminal to function like the IDLE terminal does. Any help would be much appreciated, I remember a time where it all worked an now it just seems to have all gone wrong, probably something stupid that I have done.

Uninstalling and reisntalling, removing files like .vscode, however I believe that it may be a file path issue, I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: see similar question (the previous VSC question) https://stackoverflow.com/q/77262154/9938317

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between vscode integrated terminal and python interactive terminal. The former is a system terminal, such as powershell or cmd, which only accepts command input, while the latter can directly enter and execute python code.

You can type `python` in the integrated terminal and press Enter to open the python interactive terminal.

[image]

In vscode you can also use the `Shift+Enter` shortcut key to open the python interactive terminal.

[More details here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py).